How to Filter DiscriminatorMap Based on Property in Doctrine Extension? [Api-platform]
I have a project where I'm using Doctrine inheritance with a DiscriminatorMap in my Vehicle entity, which includes a Bike entity. My goal is to create a custom Doctrine extension to filter out bikes that are not published (isPublished = false) when I fetch all vehicles using GET /vehicles.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
<?php
//...

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: VehicleRepository::class)]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'discr', type: 'string')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    'car' => Car::class,
    'bike' => Bike::class
])]
#[ApiResource]
class Vehicle
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;


<?php
//...

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BikeRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class)]
class Bike
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $isPublished = null;

I have a DiscriminatorMap relationship with Bike from Vehicle.
When I do a GET /vehicles I would like to make an extension that checks if Bike is at isPublished = true;
With this extension and this dd() I get “SELECT o FROM App\Entity\Vehicle\Vehicle o”.
How can I filter on Bike?
<?php
// ...

class DoctrineExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    public function applyToCollection(
        /* ... */
    ): void
    {
        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

        if ($resourceClass === Vehicle::class) {
            dd($queryBuilder->getDQL());
        }
    }
}

